# Angular orderBy:'timestamp' putting things in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

### What I want to do:

Take an array of objects, each object with `object.timestamp` in milliseconds, and order them from newest to oldest.

### The problem:

Angular's orderBy doesn't seem to be putting things in the correct order. The following timestamps are getting put in the following order:

1. 1416187808218 - `// Nov/16/2014 5:30:PM`
2. 1416187881192 - `// Nov/16/2014 5:31:PM`
3. 1416189118263 - `// Nov/16/2014 5:51:PM`
4. 1416189138827 - `// Nov/16/2014 5:52:PM`
5. 1416130064119 - `// Nov/16/2014 1:27:AM`

The correct/desired order is obviously be:

1. 1416189138827 - `// Nov/16/2014 5:52:PM`
2. 1416189118263 - `// Nov/16/2014 5:51:PM`
3. 1416187881192 - `// Nov/16/2014 5:31:PM`
4. 1416187808218 - `// Nov/16/2014 5:30:PM`
5. 1416130064119 - `// Nov/16/2014 1:27:AM`

So it's going `4, 3, 2, 1, 5` when it should be, obviously, `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

---

### The relavent code:

#### html:

```
<div class="cardWrapper" ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:'timestamp'">
  various child elements
</div>
```

#### javascript:

```
scope.cards = homeData.get().cards; // returns an array of objects
// ^this^ becomes something similar to
scope.cards = [
  {text: 'some text...', timestamp: 1416189138827, other: 'data'},
  {text: 'some text...', timestamp: 1416187881192, other: 'data'}
  //etc...
];
```

Comment: Don't know what you are doing, but this works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/k2h80393/

Answer (score 0):

Is your timestamp coming through your API as a string and not an integer? I realize here it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting timestamp to date and then sort using `orderBy()` in angularjs.